# grep combinado con echo

Tags: linux, bash, script, consola

estoy aprendiendo a usar la consola de linux y actualmente lo que quiero hacer es escribir en un archivo .txt "resultado encontrado" si existe cierta palabra en otro archivo.Pero estoy trancado, lo que tengo por el momento es eso:

`echo "resultado encontrado" >> resultados.txt | grep "dolar" cotizacion.txt`

no sé si existe algo para evaluar en la consola si existe la palabra en el archivo entonces que haga determinada eaccion

Comment: no puedes atrapar la salida si mandas a archivo antes, el simbolo `|` lo que hace es redireccionar la salida del comando anterior... pero en tu caso el anterior es una salida a archivo puedes hacer `echo "resultado encontrado" >> resultados.txt; echo "resultado encontrado" | grep "dolar" >> cotizacion.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con

```
$ grep -q "dolar" cotizacion.txt && echo "resultado encontrado" >> resultados.txt
```

Lo que hace el parámetro `-q` de `grep` es no imprimir nada en el stdout. Sale inmediatamente con un estado de 0, si encontró algo, incluso si un error fue detectado, o 1, si no encontró algo.

Después, el token `&&` permite que se ejecute el siguiente comando si el anterior tuvo una salida exitosa (osea un 0).

Comment: impecable la verdad me ayudaste un monton,lo unico que le cambie fue el > por >> en mi caso me sirve más el mayor mayor :)

Comment: Tienes razón, modifiqué la respuesta para agregar ese detalle que se me pasó por alto.

Comment: Cual es la diferencia entre > y >>

Comment: por lo que pude observar el > sobreescribe lo que haya en el archivo por el nuevo resultado y el >> lo agrega en otro linea.

Comment: Eso es tema de otra pregunta. Es sencillo el concepto en general, pero es interesante a detalle. @LeoOdriozola muestra la parte en general, la de la práctica cotidiana.

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear un script che ejecuta lo que quieres

**script.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
if grep "dolar"; then
   echo "some data for the file" >> resultados.txt
fi
```

para que ejcutes un script tiene que ser ejecutable haciendo el siguiente comando

`chmod +x script.sh`

y al final la ejecutas

`./script.sh`

Saludos

Comment: en mi caso lo quiero hacer directamente desde la consola.